# Same times displaying differently on local browser vs cloud browser. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datetime, ejs

I'm running both a local and a production version of my web app (hosted on Heroku). The app lets users create an `event`, so I created an event with the start time of 1:30pm CST both locally and in my production app.

Both events in their respective db's show `event_start: 2023-12-13T19:30:00.000+00:00` which is correct because they've been offset by my TZ of +6 to format as UTC. However, my local client side renders `1:30pm` while my cloud-based client side shows `7:30pm`.

The code for the client (below) is identical for each:

```html
    <p id="eventStart" class="card-text">
       <i class="bi bi-calendar2-event-fill"></i>
       <%= moment(event.event_start).format('MM/DD/YY, hh:mm a') %>
    </p>
```

Why isn't the prod version of my Chrome browser rendering the TZ adjusted time?

Comment: Because the time zone on the cloud-based client is offset from UTC by 0 hours? Moment uses the time zone of the current JavaScript host when rendering dates (if you are not using moment-timezone).

Comment: What do you mean by "cloud browser" and "prod version of my Chrome browser"?

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, you summarized what I'm trying to say. For some reason, my browser doesn't apply the offset when rendering my production app but it does for my local app (I'm not using moment tz). Do you know why that's happening?

Comment: I don't know ejs, but if the code within `<%= ... %>` is running on the server, and the server's time zone is set to UTC, it would render the time as 7:30pm. Running locally on your computer, which is set to your time zone, it would render the time adjusted to your offset, which would be 1:30pm. That's how time zones work ‍♂️

Comment: Ahhh, that's a good callout @HereticMonkey . `event.start_time` IS coming from the server so I logged it in each environment and it's logging as `2023-12-13T19:30:00.000Z`. I do think you're onto something though... I wonder if my local server is passing the timezone to the client but the prod server isn'??